# Swift 3: 'Doesn't match any overloaded Audio' error when using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to add audio when pressing a button, but I'm getting the following error

> "argument labels contentsOfURL, error doesn't match any overloaded Audio"

```
var ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Slag", ofType: "m4a")!)
var clickAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class UIViewController: UIViewController {
clickAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contensOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error: nil) //This is in this line i get the error

}
@IBAction func ASButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

The error happens in

```
clickAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contensOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error: nil)
```

Comment: what about here? this still open? i have a code running audio

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0, compiled successfully, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "mp3")!)
    audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)

    print("test: \(audioURL), \(audioPlayer)")
  }
}
```